# How to change the date color for weekends only(should be different from enabled and dsabled date colors) using react-native-calendars npm package?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have been using [react-native-calendars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendars) for my purpose as it almost covers all the requirements for us but I got stock when I try to modify the date colors of only weeekends to something different with  markingType={'multi-dot'}

[image]

```
<CalendarList
      data-test="calendar-list"
      current={initialDate}
      onDayPress={onDayPress}
      markedDates={marked}
      hideArrows={true}
      style={{
        height: calendarHeight
      }}
      hideExtraDays={false}
      hideDayNames={false}
      markingType={'multi-dot'}
      showWeekNumbers={false}
      disableAllTouchEventsForDisabledDays={true}
      showSixWeeks={true}
      onMonthChange={onMonthChange}          
      theme={CalendarTheme}
      horizontal={horizontalView}
      pagingEnabled={horizontalView}
    />

export const CalendarTheme = {
  calendarBackground: '#ffffff00',
  dayTextColor: colours.white,
  textDisabledColor: colours.textlight,
  monthTextColor: '#888',
  selectedDayTextColor: colours.text,
  textDayFontSize: 16,
  textMonthFontSize:16,
  textDayHeaderFontSize: 16,
};
```

As you can see from above image I have been using CalendarList with multi-dot marking type now I just need to provide different color for all the weekends.Any way to achive the above

I have tried to go through the above npm package and cannot able to find out how to achive this.